# In Kafka, how to handle deleted rows from source table that are already reflected in Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using a JDBC source connector with mode timestamp+incrementing to fetch table from Postgres, using Kafka Connect. The updates in data are reflected in Kafka topic but the deletion of records has no effect. So, my questions are:

1. Is there some way to handle deleted records?
2. How to handle records that are deleted but still present in kafka topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation is to either 1) adjust your source database to be append/update only, as well, either via a boolean or timestamp that is filtered out when Kafka Connect queries the table.

If your database is running out of space, then you can delete old records, which should already have been processed by Kafka

Option 2) Use CDC tools to capture delete events immediately rather than missing them in a period table scan. Debezium is a popular option for Postgres

Comment: I will try using option 2. Thanx!

Comment: Please help me fix my issue [Delete mode fails in JDBC Connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/1172), [How to delete records in the database through Kafka JDBC connector?](https://forum.confluent.io/t/how-to-delete-records-in-the-database-through-kafka-jdbc-connector/3996)Thanks.

Comment: @WillieCheng I already wrote my answer in the second link there

Answer (score 0):

A Kafka topic can be seen as an "append-only" log. It keeps all meesages for as long as you like but Kafka is not built to delete individual messages out of a topic.

In the scenario you are describing it is common that the downstream application (consuming the topic) handles the information on a deleted record.

As an alternative you could set the `cleanup.policy` of your topic to `compact` which means it will eventually keep only the latest value for each key. If you now define the key of a message as the primary key of the Postgres table, your topic will eventually delete the record when you produce a message with the same key and a `null` value into the topic. However,

1. I am not sure if your connector is flexible to do this
2. Depending on what you do with the data in the kafka topic, this could still not be a solution to your problem as the downstream application will still read both record, the original one and the `null` message as the deleted record.

Comment: While using the primary key as key in Kafka message, can you please direct me in how we can identify deleted records in Kafka and generate `null` value for the identified key.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misinterpreted your question. I thought a record will first be deleted within your Postgres table. This record has a (primary) key which will then be used to write a null value into Kafka. When this message gets compacted by Kafka you will not be able to identify the deleted record anymore, because it is deleted... What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Here, I am facing trouble in the source connector end. In Kafka, I am unable to create a null value for the primary key record that is being deleted in the Postgres table.